# Cannot read property of "label" of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, bar-chart, angular-chart

I want to build a simple bar chart using Chart.js (1.0.2) and angular-chart.js (0.8.5).  I read lots of other articles about this problem, but nothing helped. So this is the case:

I get "shipdata" from my RequestService which include a type, an hour and a count per type&hour. So it looks something like that:

`Object {hour: "0", type: "9", count: "66"}
Object {hour: "0", type: "3", count: "195"}`

Then i select unique hours and types: hours are my labels and type is the series. After that I build the data array. This works perfectly fine and as a result i have in the end:

**$scope.labels**: `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "17", "18"]`

**$scope.series**: `["0", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9"]`

**$scope.data**: `0: Array[10]1: Array[10]2: Array[10]3: Array[10]4: Array[10]5: Array[10]6: Array[10]7: Array[10]8: Array[10]9: Array[10]10: Array[10]11: Array[10]12: Array[10]17: Array[10]18: Array[10]`

*I printed those results in the command line.*

Now everytime I call the $scope.getChartData() function, i get the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined**

Here is the code to the `$scope.getChartData()` :
http://pastebin.com/7kWQ6W09

Here is the view: http://pastebin.com/0DvDcMBa

I tried serveral times the example provided on the angular-js github page (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). However I don't get why their example works pretty fine and mine, which provides exactly the same data, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing label outside the call to the service, why not trying to initialize after?

please try to change this

```
    var allData = [];
    $scope.series = [];
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [[]];
    RequestService.getShipTypes(nelat, swlat, nelng, swlng, date, analyse)
            .success(function(ships) {
```

to this

```
    RequestService.getShipTypes(nelat, swlat, nelng, swlng, date, analyse)
            .success(function(ships) {
    var allData = [];
    $scope.series = [];
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [[]];
```

Comment: you didnt show how you call your controller, is everything ok?

Comment: yes, everything else in the controller works fine and i didn't change anything apart of the bar chart part. I call the getChartData() via a Button in the view.